# Loop ending condition is not working - C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, dynamic

I have a homework regarding dynamic arrays, therefore I was trying to understand how it works with simple programs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int cnt,i=0;
    char temp[1001];
    char *obj[5];

    scanf("%d",cnt);

    while(i<cnt){

        scanf("%s",temp);
        obj[i]=malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(temp)+1));
        obj[i]=temp;
        printf("%s\n",obj[i]);
        printf("%d\n",i);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When i get the "cnt" to be equal to 5, by reading from stdin, the program is running forever, though ending condition meets. But when i get the "cnt" to be equal to 5, by assigning it, at the very beginning of the program (not by using scanf) the program works just fine.
What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation of the function you're using? Why don't you study general concepts in C (like the fact that function arguments are pass-by-value only)? -1 for no effort and a bad, duplicate question.

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
scanf("%d",cnt);
```

should be:

```
/* Always check return value of scanf(),
   which returns the number of assignments made,
   to ensure the variables have been assigned a value. */
if (scanf("%d",&cnt) == 1)
{
}
```

as `scanf()` requires the *address of* `cnt`.

Also:

- [Don't cast result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` so can be omitted from the space calculation in `malloc()`.
- Check result of `malloc()` to ensure memory was allocated.
- `free()` whatever was `malloc()`d.
- Prevent buffer overrun with `scanf("%s")` by specifying the maximum number of characters to read, which must be one less than the target buffer to allow a space for the terminating null character. In your case `scanf("%1000s", temp)`.
- There is no protection for out of bounds access on the array `obj`. The `while` loop's terminating condition is `i<cnt` but if `cnt > 5` the an out of bounds access will occur, causing undefined behaviour.

This assigns the address of `temp` to `obj[i]`:

```
obj[i]=temp;
```

it does *not copy* (and causes a memory leak). Use `strcpy()` instead:

```
obj[i] = malloc(strlen(temp) +1 );
if (obj[i])
{
    strcpy(obj[i], temp);
}
```

Comment: +1 especially for checking the return value, this is way too rare.

Comment: sizeof(char) is highly likely to be 1, but it is not a guarantee.

Comment: @mah, it is guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @mah **it is guaranteed to be one.**

Comment: On a 16 bit DSP it's one? Yes, there are processors whose `char` is 16 bits.

Comment: @mah, yes, the `sizeof` operator is defined with respect to `char`, regardless of the number of bits in `char`. Thus `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.

Answer (score 1):

you should use this

```
scanf("%d",&cnt);
```

BTW:

```
scanf("%s",temp);
```

is used in a while loop to read your strings. you have to add space at the beginning of the format specifier to avoid the newline problems. it should be `" %s"`

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behavior. You need to pass the address of the variable to `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%d", &cnt);
```

But you better not use `scanf()` anyway. `fgets()` is simpler and safer to use.

Comment: What is your objection to using `scanf`, here?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour 1. As currenly used, you have little to no control over what happens. 1. OP doesn't seem to be checking the return value of `scanf()`, so if it fails, the failure won't be indicated. 2. `scanf()` won't scan entire strings with spaces in them without advanced hacking on character groups, `fgets()` simply returns an entire line which will be available **whenever** it is needed. 3. For that very same reason, using `fgets()` is flexible, since you get a line you can parse as you would like to, 4. `fgets()` explicitly requires a buffer size to be provided -> fail safe.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour (You can do that with `scanf()` too, but *no beginner on Earth ever* will write `scanf("%*s", sizeof(buf), buf);`)

Comment: You seem to have many misunderstandings regarding `scanf`. When I ask what your objection to using `scanf` is, I mean *using `scanf` correctly*. It is possible to misuse *virtually any* feature of C, and the results are hideous and/or disastrous. That includes `fgets`. `scanf` doesn't *scan* anything, let alone *strings*. It reads input, which isn't in the form of *strings* but characters (there is a difference) and translates the characters to the corresponding types. `fgets` doesn't perform this translation,

Comment: ... and in order to perform this translation, extra processing (eg. in the form of `sscanf`) is required. Would you also suggest ignoring the return value of `sscanf`? That could result in undefined behaviour. Why not just use `scanf` (correctly) to begin with? Do note that `scanf`s `%*s` doesn't seem to cause the same functionality that you believe it does.

Comment: You might also want to check the validity of "*`fgets()` simply returns an entire line which will be available whenever it is needed.*" I can think of two circumstances where that isn't the case.